# Troubleshooting simple UDP connection between 2 Pycom microprocessors (Micropython)

Tags: udp, micropython

I am trying to send some byte data from a Pycom LoPy4 to a Pycom WiPy via a UDP transmission.

I have tried to get my client (lopy4) to point to the server’s (Wipy) ip address, by setting the ip address of the server side to a static IP **‘192.168.0.105’** using the .ifconfig() method. Then, I used the .sendto() method to send some data to the same IP address **‘192.168.0.105’**.

My client is able to send the data, but my server is still not receiving anything.

This is my server code:

```
import usocket
from network import WLAN

wlan = WLAN()

## Set static IP address for server
wlan.ifconfig(id = 1, config=('192.168.0.105', '255.255.255.0','192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.1'))

## Set WLAN mode to AP (access point)
wlan.init(mode = WLAN.AP, ssid = 'lopy4_server', auth = None, channel=7, antenna=WLAN.INT_ANT)
print("wlan mode set up: without auth\n")

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"    ## localhost
UDP_PORT = 5005

## Set up UDP socket and bind
sock = usocket.socket(usocket.AF_INET,usocket.SOCK_DGRAM) ## UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
print('binded')

data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) ## buffer size is 1024 bytes
print("received message:", data)
print("source: ", addr)
```

This is my client code:

```
import usocket
import utime
from network import WLAN

## Set WLAN mode to STA (station/client)
wlan = WLAN(mode = WLAN.STA)

wlan.scan()     ## scan for available networks
wlan.connect('lopy4_server', auth = None)

while not wlan.isconnected():
    pass
print(wlan.ifconfig())


UDP_IP = '192.168.0.105'
UDP_PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = "Test message"

## Set up UDP socket and connect
sock = usocket.socket(usocket.AF_INET,usocket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
while True:
    print ("UDP target IP:", UDP_IP)
    print ("UDP target port:", UDP_PORT)
    print ("message:", MESSAGE)
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    utime.sleep(3)
```

This was the output I received (left server, right client):

[image]

I suspect the problem has got to do with the IP addresses I've used, but I can't seem to find the cause. I'm hoping someone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to bind to 0.0.0.0 but not to loopback (127.0.0.1). change it to ```UDP_IP = "0.0.0.0"``` in server

Comment: Another good place to ask is on the PyCom forums.